# How to make Railo/OpenBD process files under Tomcat <Context/> nodes?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo, contextpath, openbd

I have a Tomcat host defined like this, with the WEB-INF of Railo OR OpenBD in the webapps/ROOT directory.

```
<Host name="daves.cool.website.com"  appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="/remote" docBase="/full/path/to/remotedirectory" />
</Host>
```

If I put a CFM file under the ROOT of my webapps directory, it is processed as expected by either Railo or OpenBD.  When I move that same file to the remotedirectory, it is returned as unparsed text with straight CFML code.  How can I instruct the appserver to have OpenBD or Railo process files in the defined Context directories?

[edit: this is a Windows server]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a web application deployed in the remotedirectory, i.e., an exploded Railo or OpenBD WAR file.

Comment: This appears to be the answer, but that doesn't mean I like it!  Ideally I want to have multiple tomcat instances, each with a WEB-INF under the ROOT, with Context nodes pointing to a single source directory.  Given the environment, and trying to make a case for moving from ACF, one of my goals is to reduce the level of change/fear by leaving things that they have grown accustomed to intact.

Comment: Tomcat can have its web applications anywhere, but a web application is the web root including the WEB-INF tree. You can run lots of web applications on a single instance of Tomcat. You can also configure Tomcat and Railo so that the WEB-INF tree is auto-deployed to each new webroot that is added.